# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '[FIRApp configure] Firebase Analytics is not available.'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am stucked with the above error after launched the app. I am using Firebase SDK (manual, without cocoapod). Tried all possible suggestion mentioned before for this,but nothing helps.

Here my code of `AppDelegate.swift`:

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 0):

Add `import Firebase` at the top, to include Firebase framework. This will fix the issue.